# Latex: PDF does not print the bibliography from the .bib file

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

I am trying to put the bibliography in my .tex file, but it does not work. I think I have still some problems with biber/biblatex. I already updated all biblatex files through miktex update manager. But I still become the error:

> Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
>   (biblatex) myfile
>   (biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

and

> empty bibliography

and so on.

I've tryed all possible things, nothing helped me. 
And I do run correctly PDFLaTeX + Biblatex + 2PDFLaTeX.
I use TexMaker.
My preamble looks like this:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
```

Comment: Alex, this question is better suited for [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a cross-network duplicate has already been posted on [tex.se]: [LaTeX: PDF does not print the bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348225/5764)